PDFsharp not providing good compression
I'm working in a console application targeting .NET v8. I'm using PDFsharp nuget package for PDF file generation. I'm using below code to compress a PDF file of 75 KB. The PDF file mostly contains text.
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\test.pdf")) { Position = 0 })
using (var source = PdfReader.Open(stream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
using (var document = new PdfDocument())
{
    var options = document.Options;
    options.FlateEncodeMode = PdfFlateEncodeMode.BestCompression;
    options.UseFlateDecoderForJpegImages = PdfUseFlateDecoderForJpegImages.Automatic;
    options.CompressContentStreams = true;
    options.NoCompression = false;
    options.EnableCcittCompressionForBilevelImages = true;

    foreach (var page in source.Pages)
    {
        document.AddPage(page);
    }

    document.Save("D:\\testout.pdf");
}

The output file that I get is of 73 KB. So I get reduction of 2 KB only. Is there any way to reduce its size significantly using compression?

I'm doing something similar with another PDF library and basically I manually extract all images, run them trough external compressors (like e.g. pingo) and then put them back into the PDF again.

My input file has 90 to 95% text. Only one small image. So image compression can't help.

73 KB for a PDF with an image (even if it is a small one) doesn't sound that bad to me. Just for testing purposes, I would try using the same PDF but without the image. Just to be absolutely sure it really is not the image that causes this.

PDF file without image is 72.4 KB. So image is of 2.6 KB only.

The embedded fonts will contribute to the size of the PDF file. Trying different font settings (ANSI vs. Unicode) can make a difference. As of version 6.1.1, using ANSI may lead to smaller files if you have much text while Unicode may be more efficient if there is little text. A simpler font, e.g. Segoe WP, can also lead to smaller PDF files.

@RBT please post a link to the sample PDF file and I'll take a look at it. Maybe the file is already compressed as much as possible.

Enabling PdfFlateEncodeMode.BestCompression will typically reduce the size by about 2% to 5%.
With the default settings, contents are already "zipped". Best compression is more effective, but slower.
PDFsharp does not yet support object XREF streams, so other libraries may be able to create even smaller files without losses.
And, as far as I know, some settings will only have an effect when creating the PDF file in the first place, as they only apply when objects are created. When copying pages from one document to another, the elements of the pages are copied as they are, and maybe with a lower compression mode.

@RBT Make sure to set the compression parameters when creating the file in the first place.
